ffmpeg h264_amf on Windows 10 fails with CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed
Trying to use hardware encoding with ffmpeg (version 7.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev)  on Windows 10
Command
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -v verbose -c:v h264_amf -acodec copy -y <output_file>

Error
[h264_amf @ 0000014dc3388580] AMF initialisation succeeded via D3D11.
[h264_amf @ 0000014dc3388900] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderVCE_AVC) failed with error 36
[vost#0:0/h264_amf @ 0000014dc3bf7c80] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.

How to resolve this ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Error 36 is AMF_ENCODER_NOT_PRESENT i.e. your GPU does not have the fixed function block for encoding.
